# Need a formula for a conditional formatting of a cell based on another cell's data

Tags: ms-office

I'm trying to highlight a cell based on another cell's data

Example:

```
  A               B
 100% (green)     1
   0% (red)       1 or greater
   0% (white)     0
```

So I need to conditional column A so that if it shows 100% Green, 0% with a 1 or greater in B Red, and if it's 0% with a 0 in B white.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your tag indicates maybe you are using excel for Mac? Which version?

Comment: @BrandonWard I edited your question. Please check if it is fine like it is now. Also add the possible values (e.g. integers or (0|1|2)) in column B.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `Conditional Format` is what you are looking for.

Select the cell which have to be formatted and choose `Format->Conditional Format` in the menu of Excel.

For more information have a look at: [use a formula to apply conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-FED60DFA-1D3F-4E13-9ECB-F1951FF89D7F)